# ubuntu 16.04.1 grub2 for windows10

Tags: boot, grub2, 16.04, windows

Assuming I have installed W10 and I install Ubuntu 16.04.1 on unallocated space GRUB 2 will be installed automatically and will maintain booting for W10/ubuntu (automatically)?

Comment: If both are installed in UEFI or both installed in BIOS boot mode. And if Windows is not hibernated which Windows 8 or later always is, with its fast start up setting. Also if Windows needs chkdsk grub will not boot it. So best to have a Windows repair disk to fix Windows. You should have that flash drive for Windows whether you install Ubuntu or not. If UEFI you can directly boot Windows or Ubuntu/grub from UEFI boot menu. But some brands of  systems require various work arounds. What brand/mode system?

Comment: @oldfred By Windows repair disk u mean normal recovery drive created with Windows? Fast start up can be disabled. I will install _en-gb_windows_10_education_version_1607_updated_jul_2016_x64_dvd_9055967_ and _ubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-amd64_ in BIOS legacy.